# ArcGIS Pro Layout Ruler Misalignment

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

After re-installing ArcGIS Pro 3.0.1 (my computer was replaced) I am suddenly faced with a new issue.  When I am in a Layout, the rulers are not aligned to the page.  The 0 (zero) point on both the horizontal and vertical rulers is not aligned to the edge of the page.  Specifically, their intersection should coincide with the lower left corner of the page.  While the vertical (Y-axis) ruler appears to be offset by a fixed amount, the offset of the horizontal ruler (X-axis) increases or decreases based on the zoom level or the distance from the upper left corner of the screen.  This issue was not present in my APRX files before the re-installation.

My workaround is to set the zoom level at 97% and hold a ruler to the screen to be able to see exactly where I need to place elements, as well as doing a lot of arithmetic to find the coordinates necessary for exact placement of elements.  In the properties of an element, the corner coordinates show the correct values, and the guide lines appear on-screen in the right locations, but their little triangle-shaped handles in the ruler are also offset, which makes moving guide lines difficult.

Since I have a fresh, clean installation on a new computer, I'm not sure if re-installing the software again is going to fix this issue.

Comment: My problem with x-axis went away when I discovered the display was not set to 100% but to 103%. Sorry, I don't remember if there was a y-axis issue or if I fixed this in Windows or ArcGIS Pro.